# Spring Boot Build Native Error during Compilation

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven, spring-native

Error Logs and Explannation

Hello

I´ve installed boot native support and I am receiving an error.

This post is more to support and give information for the technical team to improve this beta version.

The project compiles without problem if we run "normally"

Command :  `mvn -Pnative spring-boot:build-image`

POM

```xml
<project>
    <parent>
        <groupId>parent</groupId>
        <artifactId>pom</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <relativePath>/envconfigfiles/pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>

    <groupId>spring</groupId>
    <artifactId>configuration.server</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>configuration.server</name>
    <description>Spring Configuration Server</description>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- Spring Config Server -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Tests -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>

        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>

    </build>

</project>
```

Parent POM

```xml
    <groupId>parent</groupId>
    <artifactId>pom</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <description>Environment Parent POM</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <properties>

        <apache.commons.lang3>3.8.1</apache.commons.lang3>
        <apache.httpcomponents>4.3.4</apache.httpcomponents>

        <hibernate.types.52>2.9.3</hibernate.types.52>

        <io.springfox.swagger2>2.9.2</io.springfox.swagger2>
        <io.springfox.swagger.ui>2.9.2</io.springfox.swagger.ui>
        <io.swagger.annotations>1.5.20</io.swagger.annotations>
        <io.swagger.bean.validators>2.9.2</io.swagger.bean.validators>

        <java.version>11</java.version>

        <jaxb-api>2.3.0</jaxb-api>
        <jaxb-impl>2.3.0</jaxb-impl>
        <jaxb-runtime>2.3.0</jaxb-runtime>
        <javax.activation>1.1.1</javax.activation>

        <junit.vintage.engine.version>5.3.2</junit.vintage.engine.version>

        <maven.checkstyle.version>3.0.0</maven.checkstyle.version>
        <maven.compiler.plugin>3.8.1</maven.compiler.plugin>
        <maven.jacoco.plugin>0.8.2</maven.jacoco.plugin>
        <maven.failsafe.plugin>2.22.2</maven.failsafe.plugin>
        <maven.surefire.plugin>2.22.2</maven.surefire.plugin>

        <mockito.core>3.11.0</mockito.core>

        <postgresql>42.2.23</postgresql>
        <projectlombok>1.18.20</projectlombok>

        <puppycrawl.checkstyle.version>8.19</puppycrawl.checkstyle.version>

        <spring-boot-admin.version>2.3.1</spring-boot-admin.version>
        <spring-boot-admin-server-ui-login>1.5.7</spring-boot-admin-server-ui-login>
        <spring-boot-admin-starter-client>2.4.1</spring-boot-admin-starter-client>
        <spring-boot-starter-security>2.4.0</spring-boot-starter-security>
        <spring-boot-spring-native>0.10.0</spring-boot-spring-native>

        <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.3</spring-cloud.version>
        <spring-cloud-starter-zipkin>2.2.8.RELEASE</spring-cloud-starter-zipkin>

        <spring-native.version>0.10.1</spring-native.version>

    </properties>

    <!-- MVN PROFILES -->
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>native</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <classifier>${repackage.classifier}</classifier>
                            <image>
                                <builder>paketobuildpacks/builder:tiny</builder>
                                <env>
                                    <BP_NATIVE_IMAGE>true</BP_NATIVE_IMAGE>
                                </env>
                            </image>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.experimental</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-aot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${spring-native.version}</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>test-generate</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>test-generate</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                            <execution>
                                <id>generate</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>generate</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Admin Client -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-starter-client</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot-admin-starter-client}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Cloud Client -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Native AOT Client -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.experimental</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-native</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot-spring-native}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.experimental</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aot</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot-spring-native}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Swagger -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>${io.springfox.swagger.ui}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-bean-validators</artifactId>
            <version>${io.swagger.bean.validators}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${io.swagger.annotations}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>${io.springfox.swagger2}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- DB -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>${postgresql}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vladmihalcea</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-types-52</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.types.52}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Apache Libs -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>${apache.commons.lang3}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Lombok -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>${projectlombok}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--XML Additional -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jaxb-api}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>${jaxb-impl}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>${jaxb-runtime}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
            <version>${javax.activation}</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>

        <dependencies>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-boot-admin.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>

        </dependencies>

    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>

        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>

        <plugins>

            <!--CheckStyle -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.checkstyle.version}</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.puppycrawl.tools</groupId>
                        <artifactId>checkstyle</artifactId>
                        <version>${puppycrawl.checkstyle.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>validate</id>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <excludes>
                            </excludes>
                            <configLocation>checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
                            <consoleOutput>true</consoleOutput>
                            <logViolationsToConsole>false</logViolationsToConsole>
                            <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>check</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <!--Compiler With Lombok -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.compiler.plugin}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>${projectlombok}</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                    <useIncrementalCompilation>false</useIncrementalCompilation> <!-- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MCOMPILER-209 -->
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!--Jacoco Test Report -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.jacoco.plugin}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>report</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <!-- SureFire - Run Unit Tests -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.surefire.plugin}</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
                        <version>${junit-jupiter.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <configuration>
                    <forkedProcessExitTimeoutInSeconds>240</forkedProcessExitTimeoutInSeconds>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*.class</include>
                    </includes>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/*_FT.java</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                    <useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Run Functional Tests -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.failsafe.plugin}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>api-tests</id>
                        <phase>none</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <testSourceDirectory>src/test/java/functionaltests</testSourceDirectory>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*FT*</include>
                            </includes>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <forkedProcessExitTimeoutInSeconds>240</forkedProcessExitTimeoutInSeconds>
                    <useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader>
                    <trimStackTrace>false</trimStackTrace>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Spring Boot -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludeDevtools>false</excludeDevtools>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>

        <repository>
            <id>spring-release</id>
            <name>Spring release</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/release</url>
        </repository>

    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>

        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-release</id>
            <name>Spring release</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/release</url>
        </pluginRepository>

    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

Error Log

```
14270573607ffcd469159237568469f010e2f97bd74f674f79c38364f'
[INFO]  > Executing lifecycle version v0.11.3
[INFO]  > Using build cache volume 'pack-cache-a930304ae2dd.build'
[INFO] 
[INFO]  > Running creator
[INFO]     [creator]     ===> DETECTING
[INFO]     [creator]     5 of 12 buildpacks participating
[INFO]     [creator]     paketo-buildpacks/ca-certificates 2.3.2
[INFO]     [creator]     paketo-buildpacks/graalvm         6.2.2
[INFO]     [creator]     paketo-buildpacks/executable-jar  5.1.2
[INFO]     [creator]     paketo-buildpacks/spring-boot     4.4.2
[INFO]     [creator]     paketo-buildpacks/native-image    4.1.2
[INFO]     [creator]     ===> ANALYZING
[INFO]     [creator]     Previous image with name "docker.io/library/configuration.server:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT" not found
[INFO]     [creator]     ===> RESTORING
[INFO]     [creator]     ===> BUILDING
[INFO]     [creator]     
[INFO]     [creator]     Paketo CA Certificates Buildpack 2.3.2
[INFO]     [creator]       https://github.com/paketo-buildpacks/ca-certificates
[INFO]     [creator]       Launch Helper: Contributing to layer
[INFO]     [creator]         Creating /layers/paketo-buildpacks_ca-certificates/helper/exec.d/ca-certificates-helper
[INFO]     [creator]     
[INFO]     [creator]     Paketo GraalVM Buildpack 6.2.2
[INFO]     [creator]       https://github.com/paketo-buildpacks/graalvm
[INFO]     [creator]       Build Configuration:
[INFO]     [creator]         $BP_JVM_VERSION              11.*            the Java version
[INFO]     [creator]       Launch Configuration:
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_JVM_HEAD_ROOM           0               the headroom in memory calculation
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_JVM_LOADED_CLASS_COUNT  35% of classes  the number of loaded classes in memory calculation
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_JVM_THREAD_COUNT        250             the number of threads in memory calculation
[INFO]     [creator]         $JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS                           the JVM launch flags
[INFO]     [creator]       GraalVM JDK 11.0.11: Contributing to layer
[INFO]     [creator]         Downloading from https://github.com/graalvm/graalvm-ce-builds/releases/download/vm-21.1.0/graalvm-ce-java11-linux-amd64-21.1.0.tar.gz
[INFO]     [creator]         Verifying checksum
[INFO]     [creator]         Expanding to /layers/paketo-buildpacks_graalvm/jdk
[INFO]     [creator]         Adding 129 container CA certificates to JVM truststore
[INFO]     [creator]       GraalVM Native Image Substrate VM 11.0.11
[INFO]     [creator]         Downloading from https://github.com/graalvm/graalvm-ce-builds/releases/download/vm-21.1.0/native-image-installable-svm-java11-linux-amd64-21.1.0.jar
[INFO]     [creator]         Verifying checksum
[INFO]     [creator]         Installing substrate VM
[INFO]     [creator]     Processing Component archive: /tmp/1ab725616fede21ad5ae900d00ec6d45753db6f6f4fe51a836d538c79d79614a/native-image-installable-svm-java11-linux-amd64-21.1.0.jar
[INFO]     [creator]     Installing new component: Native Image (org.graalvm.native-image, version 21.1.0)
[INFO]     [creator]         Writing env.build/JAVA_HOME.override
[INFO]     [creator]         Writing env.build/JDK_HOME.override
[INFO]     [creator]     
[INFO]     [creator]     Paketo Executable JAR Buildpack 5.1.2
[INFO]     [creator]       https://github.com/paketo-buildpacks/executable-jar
[INFO]     [creator]       Class Path: Contributing to layer
[INFO]     [creator]         Writing env.build/CLASSPATH.delim
[INFO]     [creator]         Writing env.build/CLASSPATH.prepend
[INFO]     [creator]     
[INFO]     [creator]     Paketo Spring Boot Buildpack 4.4.2
[INFO]     [creator]       https://github.com/paketo-buildpacks/spring-boot
[INFO]     [creator]       Class Path: Contributing to layer
[INFO]     [creator]         Writing env.build/CLASSPATH.append
[INFO]     [creator]         Writing env.build/CLASSPATH.delim
[INFO]     [creator]       Image labels:
[INFO]     [creator]         org.opencontainers.image.title
[INFO]     [creator]         org.opencontainers.image.version
[INFO]     [creator]         org.springframework.boot.version
[INFO]     [creator]     
[INFO]     [creator]     Paketo Native Image Buildpack 4.1.2
[INFO]     [creator]       https://github.com/paketo-buildpacks/native-image
[INFO]     [creator]       Build Configuration:
[INFO]     [creator]         $BP_NATIVE_IMAGE                  true  enable native image build
[INFO]     [creator]         $BP_NATIVE_IMAGE_BUILD_ARGUMENTS        arguments to pass to the native-image command
[INFO]     [creator]       Native Image: Contributing to layer
[INFO]     [creator]         GraalVM 21.1.0 Java 11 CE (Java Version 11.0.11+8-jvmci-21.1-b05)
[INFO]     [creator]     [/layers/paketo-buildpacks_native-image/native-image/spring.configuration.server.Application:169]     (clinit):   2,872.18 ms,  2.60 GB
[INFO]     [creator]     [/layers/paketo-buildpacks_native-image/native-image/spring.configuration.server.Application:169]   (typeflow): 115,047.19 ms,  2.60 GB
[INFO]     [creator]     [/layers/paketo-buildpacks_native-image/native-image/spring.configuration.server.Application:169]    (objects): 274,851.84 ms,  2.60 GB
[INFO]     [creator]     [/layers/paketo-buildpacks_native-image/native-image/spring.configuration.server.Application:169]   (features):  11,603.11 ms,  2.60 GB
[INFO]     [creator]     [/layers/paketo-buildpacks_native-image/native-image/spring.configuration.server.Application:169]     analysis: 409,017.77 ms,  2.60 GB
[INFO]     [creator]     [/layers/paketo-buildpacks_native-image/native-image/spring.configuration.server.Application:169]     universe:   5,672.85 ms,  2.60 GB
[INFO]     [creator]     Error: Image build request failed with exit status 137
[INFO]     [creator]     unable to invoke layer creator
[INFO]     [creator]     unable to contribute native-image layer
[INFO]     [creator]     error running build
[INFO]     [creator]     exit status 137
[INFO]     [creator]     ERROR: failed to build: exit status 1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  09:15 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-07-18T23:20:49+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.5.2:build-image (default-cli) on project configuration.server: Execution default-cli of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.5.2:build-image failed: Builder lifecycle 'creator' failed with status code 145 -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] `enter code here
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
```

Comment: I have more logs, but limit is 30000 chars, if you want i can send by e-mail.

Comment: No need full logs you can specify caused by line only enough.